# Debug mode linkage fails due to unsigned int initialization in header

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

As far as I know all integer types can be initialized in the header file.
That's why I felt that this kind of declaration was correct in one of my headers (lets call it foo.h):

```
class Foo {
public:
  static const unsigned int DEFAULT = 0xffffffff;
  ...
};
```

And it worked, when compiling and linking in release mode.
However, when I compiled the code in debug mode I got the following error:

```
undefined reference to `Bar::Foo::DEFAULT'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I moved the initialization to foo.cpp the problem was solved:

```
const unsigned int Foo::DEFAULT = 0xffffffff;
```

But I don't understand why. Can somebody guess?

(I use gcc 4.2.4 on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've **initialized** the member but **not defined** it. You still need the `const unsigned int Foo::DEFAULT;` in a single implementation file.

In a release build, references to the member are probably optimized away (i.e. replaced inline with the value since you're telling the compiler it isn't going to get changed) so no symbols are looked up. Debug isn't that lenient - the compiler now wants to know that your member is defined and resides somewhere in memory.